# Mysqli to PDO conversion

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I recently started using PDO a few days ago and am changing all my mysqli code but I seem to have hit a brick wall. Now this code worked beautifully when I was using mysqli, but now I can't seem to print out the result. This code basically takes the input value of password, and that of the hashed password in the database, matches them and if both are equal then the user will be logged in. My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get the password from my database. Any help would be much  appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php 
 session_start();

 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";

$mcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rabbit_users', $user, $pass);

 try {
 $mcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rabbit_users', $user, $pass);
$mcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();



//prepare statement
$password = $_POST['password']; 

$stmt = $mcon->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM members WHERE password=:password");
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST['password']);
$stmt->execute();

//get_result
$data_array = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//echo passwords
print 'Password from form: ' . $password . '<br />';
print 'Password from DB: ' . $data_array['password'] . '<br />';

//verify password
if (password_verify($password, $data_array['password'])) {
    print 'success';
    exit();
}else{
    print 'Try again m9';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you don't need to `$mcon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rabbit_users', $user, $pass);` twice.

Comment: So should I only keep the  the Connection line in the try statement only. Again thank you for your help!

Comment: if the password in the database is hashed... its not going to match the password from post in that WHERE statement... unless the post is hashed too?

Comment: @Soujirou When I was using mysqli, I would hash the $_POST password too but that's the problem now. I'm not very sure how to go about doing so. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JellalSaleh Use [password_hash](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Leggendario's answer might be the right direction, you fetched twice, see if that fixes it

Comment: @Machavity I did before but I wasn't sure how to implement it into PDO. Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"Now I just nee to hash the password"* - You mean to say that you didn't hash the password to start with?

Comment: @Soujirou Yeah, I did that and it defined my index so that's great. Now the whole hash thing. I'll get it done though haha. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh no, I did in my regristration page and login, but that was when I was using mysqli you see. I meant I didn't know how to hash in PDO. Not sure if it worked the same. Php manual was abit sideways about it haha.

Comment: @Fred-ii- And it turns out that I spelt password_hash wrong which is why it didn't work. Sometimes my level of stupidity really surprises me haha!

Comment: `mysqli_` or PDO, `password_hash()` doesn't matter which API used, just as long as you're able to access it via `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array containing all of the result set rows. So you can access to `password` with `$data_array[0]['password']` if you used it.
You may want use [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead.

```
$data_array = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :). Now I just nee to hash the password. Another way I see around the password hash issue is by creating 3 passwords (with an algo obv) and then matching the hash's of those with the hash of the actual password. But that's sort of brute forcing myself haha!